# Access child class' static members from base class

Tags: typescript

I have the following base class:

```
class BaseClass {
    public static myFlag: boolean = false;

    constructor() {
        //reference ChildClass.myFlag??
    }
}
```

With the child class:

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    constructor() { super(); }
}
```

And the following code:

```
ChildClass.myFlag = true;
var child = new ChildClass();
```

How can I reference the value of the child class' `myFlag` property without passing the child class to the base class' constructor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The context of the constructor is the child object. To access the child class' static properties, use [Object.prototype.constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor):

```
class BaseClass {
    public static myFlag: boolean = false;

    constructor() {
        console.log(this["constructor"].myFlag); // true
    }
}
```

**Update**

In newer versions of TypeScript you might need to do this for it to compile:

```
class BaseClass {
    public static myFlag: boolean = false;

    constructor() {
        const ctor = this.constructor as typeof BaseClass;
        console.log(ctor.myFlag); // true
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just write `this["constructor"].myFlag` ?