# Access child class static member from a base class static member

Tags: typescript, oop, inheritance, static

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851358/access-child-class-static-members-from-base-class) is how to access child class static member from a base class non-static member.

I'm wondering: is it doable also from a base static member?

I've tried the following code which doesn't work ([Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-access-static-child-from-static-base)):

```
export class EntityBase {
    // Base static property initialized using a child static memeber
    public static TypeName: string = (EntityBase as any).$typeName;

    public static StaticBaseMethod(): string {
      return (EntityBase as any).$typeName;
    }

    public static seeIfWorks(): any {
        return {
          field: EntityBase.TypeName,
          method: EntityBase.StaticBaseMethod()
        };
    }
}

export class Entity extends EntityBase {
    public static $typeName: string = "CoolChildType";
}

// Test call
this.test = EntityBase.seeIfWorks()
```

Both properties of object returned by `seeIfWorks()` method are `undefined`.

The problem is that there is no direct access to a child constructor function from base static members. The only way I've came so far is to pass it explicitly to the base static methods, but maybe there is language integrated solution for this problem already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer to my question is: you actually *can* refer to child static members from a base class static member. This could be done via `this` keyword instead of base class name (thanks @estus for demonstrating it in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50011346/3345644)).

As a developer mostly from class-based languages background, I've missed the option of using `this` in static members in TypeScript.

So, the example from my question could be fixed by replacing base class name with `this` whenever we want to refer to the child class static member:

```
export class EntityBase {
    // Static initializer doesn't work for the purpose, since it's called once during first usage of base class. Use static getter instead (below).
    // public static TypeName: string = (EntityBase as any).$typeName;

    // Static getter
    public static get TypeName(): string {
       return (this as any).$typeName;
    }

    public static StaticBaseMethod(): string {
      return (this as any).$typeName;
    }

    public static seeIfWorks(): any {
        return {
          field: this.TypeName,
          method: this.StaticBaseMethod()
        };
    }
}
```

Also, my typo was referring to base class instead of a child one when testing this. The correct way is:

```
// Test call
this.test = Entity.seeIfWorks()
```

See updated [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-access-static-child-from-static-base) where I also added a test case for two derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

This class hierarchy has several problems:

- static-only class is usually an antipattern in JavaScript/TypeScript
- `EntityBase` is used instead of `Entity` in `this.test = EntityBase.seeIfWorks()` example, child class isn't involved
- class constructor is hard-coded to `EntityBase` in `EntityBase`, there's no way how it can refer to `Entity` this way
- `TypeName` is hard-coded to `EntityBase.$typeName`, it can't refer to `Entity.$typeName` without redefining it in child class or using a getter
- `EntityBase` doesn't have `$typeName` property while it uses it, this is class design mistake. A property should be defined any way
- `EntityBase` can be used directly, while it isn't supposed to because of undefined `$typeName`. If it's base class, it should be `abstract`. This doesn't prevent it from using static methods (they can contain runtime  check if necessary) but designates its purpose.

It should be:

```
export abstract class EntityBase {
    static $typeName?: string;

    static get TypeName(): string {
       if (this === EntityBase) throw 'Cannot be accessed';
       return this.$typeName;
    }

    static StaticBaseMethod(): string {
       if (this === EntityBase) throw 'Cannot be accessed';
       return this.$typeName;
    }

    static seeIfWorks(): any {
       if (this === EntityBase) throw 'Cannot be accessed';
       return {
          field: this.TypeName,
          method: this.StaticBaseMethod()
        };
    }
}

export class Entity extends EntityBase {
    static $typeName: string = "CoolChildType";
}
```