# Overriding static fields for children in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, static

I have an abstract class containing a static URL and implements functions using that static URL. The children should override the static URL from class A.

But I'd still like the children to use the functions provided by their parent class A to use the static overridden URL of the child class. Is there any way to do this in Typescript?

```
interface IState {
    cashflowToPost?: CashflowObject;
    cashflowList: CashflowObject[];
}
export default abstract class CashflowListView extends React.Component<{}, IState> {
    static cashflowObject : CashflowObject;
    static getURL : URL;

    
    callApi() {
        try {
            axios.get(CashflowListView.getURL.toString()).then(response => {
                console.log("called Api");
                this.setState({cashflowList: response.data});
            })
        } catch {
            console.log("failed to call api!")
        }
    }
    


    componentDidMount() {
        this.callApi();
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Considering every class should have a URL attached to it so class based not instance based, I think static is the right way to do it? I just want the children to use their own static url in the axios call instead of  CashflowListView.getURL.toString()

Comment: You can't do that. The parent's methods will always reference the parent's static variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I thought this was not possible until I started to search about it myself. This was already answered here: [Access child class' static members from base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851358/access-child-class-static-members-from-base-class)

```js
abstract class Base {
    static url: string = "hello.com";

    log() {
        const thisConructor = this.constructor as typeof Base;
        console.log('Do it>>>', thisConructor.url);
        // => Make axios call with "thisConructor.url"
    }
}

class Child extends Base {
    static url: string = "hello1.com";
}

const c = new Child();
c.log(); // => "hello1.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I'd still like the children to use the functions provided by their parent class A to use the static overridden URL of the child class.

A child instance can certainly access methods in the parent class, but if that parent's method accesses a static property, calling it from an instance will fail:

```js
class A {
  static getURL = 'http://example.com';
  
  aMethod() {
    console.log('A.aMethod() getURL:', getURL);
  }
}

class B extends A {
  static getURL = 'http://example.com/BClass';
}

const bInstance = new B();
bInstance.aMethod(); // ReferenceError: Can't find variable: getURL
```

While you can't "override" a class's static variable, you can do something like this:

```js
class A {
  static getURL = 'http://example.com/AClass';
  
  // make the method static and pass in url
  static aMethod(url) {
    console.log('aMethod() url:', url);
  }
}

class B extends A {
  static getURL = 'http://example.com/BClass';
}

console.log('A.getURL:', A.getURL);
A.aMethod(A.getURL);

console.log('B.getURL:', B.getURL)
B.aMethod(B.getURL);
```

But since the OP wants to reuse an instance method that references both a static property (`getURL`) and an instance property (`this`), a different strategy is needed.

### Solution: Access Static Property from a Class Constructor

Fortunately, we can take advantage of the fact that a [static property can be referenced from the instance's class constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static#calling_static_members_from_a_class_constructor_and_other_methods):

```js
   thisURL = this.constructor.getURL;
```

`this.constructor.getURL` references the static property `getURL` of the instance's class (not the parent's class).

```js
class A {
  static getURL = 'http://AClassURL';

  aInstanceMethod() {
    // `this.constructor.getURL` references the instance's class
    this.result = `result obtained using ${this.constructor.getURL}`;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  static getURL = 'http://BClassURL';
}


const aInstance = new A();
aInstance.aInstanceMethod();

const bInstance = new B();
bInstance.aInstanceMethod();


document.querySelector('pre').innerText =
  `A.getURL = ${A.getURL}
B.getURL = ${B.getURL}

aInstance: ${JSON.stringify(aInstance, null, 2)}

bInstance: ${JSON.stringify(bInstance, null, 2)}`;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But say instead of a URL I wanted to have a static 1 Gigabyte image, and saving this as a field for each instance would prove slow. And I had a lot of code written using that static image for my parent class. And I'd like to use another static image for a child class. Would I have to rewrite the functions using that large image in the parent class in the child classes?

Comment: @Esnaj See my updated answer, which [accesses static members via the class constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static#calling_static_members_from_a_class_constructor_and_other_methods). Also the answer from [Kiran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66197937/3113485).